# How do I reset pre-installed Ubuntu 18.04 LTS to default configuration?

Tags: 18.04

I have a computer with Ubuntu 18.04 LTS preinstallated. The thing is that I made a terrible mistake with one programme and now it's impossible to me to get the same configuration as before of this programme. So I would like to get Ubuntu 18.04 as the first day. I don't want to remove Ubuntu 18.04 which is pre-installed I want to get the initial configuration without any other programmes installed by me.

Thank you, a lot

Comment: Perhaps uninstalling just that package (the program and its unique dependencies) might suffice? Have you tried `sudo apt remove packahename` ?

Comment: Ask whatever vendor you purchased the preinstallation from if they added any special configuration to stock Ubuntu. We wouldn't know about that.

Comment: Ubuntu does NOT have a "System Restore" feature like Windows, since there is no Product Key or proprietary software to hide or to obfuscate. In most cases a stock clean-install of Ubuntu from a downloaded installer is identical to the pre-installed version. Of course, there is also a likelihood that the problem can be *fixed* instead of wiped.

Comment: Actually Ubuntu, or rather Linux DOES have a feature similar to Windows System Restore. It's called [Timeshift](https://www.fossmint.com/backup-restore-linux-with-timeshift/) and is easily installed. It takes a snapshot of your system anytime you require it, although it's too late now to use it to make a snapshot of your pre-installed Ubuntu.

Comment: What changed? Show us errors or not liked behaviour.

Comment: Finally, I could uninstall the program and its dependencies, which were in a hidden folder. Doing that and then reinstalling the program, solved my problem. I used this command (sudo vi /etc/apt/sources.list) to see the hidden folder and then I removed it at all. Thank you!